# Int value with a dot minus an Int

Tags: ios, swift, string, int

I want to hear if it is possible to minus two numbers, when the one value contains a (.) at the end of the number.

I have a value like this:

```
var numberOne: String = "21."
print(Int(numberOne) - 1)
```

That is not possible, it does not work. So how can I do that?

Comment: `debugPrint((Double(numberOne) ?? 0) - 1)` which prints you `20.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible because the conversion to `Int(numberOne)` will fail because of the `.`.

`Double`/`Float` will work:

```
var numberOne: String = "21."
print(Double(numberOne)! - 1) // 20.0
print(Float(numberOne)! - 1) // 20.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var numberOne: String = "21."
print(Int(Double(numberOne)!) - 1)
```

You cannot convert a string with a dot to an int but you can convert it to Float or Double and these can be converted to Int.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: How does this answer differ from my answer @DuncanC?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers focus on using an intermediate floating point conversion. An alternative (given you want to convert your `String` instance to an `Int` instance) is to separate the non-decimal part of string and use it (attempt to) initialize an integer:

```
import Foundation

var numberOne: String = "21."

if let numberAsInt = Int(numberOne.components(separatedBy: ".").first ?? "x") {
    print(numberAsInt - 1) // 20
}
```